# How do I read from web-service XML response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I send Text messages using soap webservice
here's the function:

```
public static string SendSms(string Message, string Phone, string BranchName)
{
    string result;
    try
    {
        var sms = new WebServiceSMS.SendMessageSoapClient();
        sms.SendSms(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pwd"], Message, Phone, BranchName, "0");
        result = "Successful";
        return result;
    }
    catch
    {
        result = "failed";
        return result;
    }
}
```

the XML response looks like that:

[XML Response Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2vM6.png)

how do I read from XML as webservice method call has completed?

**Update:**
[image]

Comment: It looks like you've added the service via service reference, so the object returned by `SendSms` should be an object (class) of some sort.  Hover over the SendSms method in Visual Studio and it should tell you what it returns.

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot. It seems like it does not return anything after all?

Comment: Hmm...looks like it's returning XML as a string.  You'll need to parse the XML then.  I'll post an example shorlty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking to return the XML response from sms.SendSMS():

```
public static string SendSms(string Message, string Phone, string BranchName)
{
    try
    {
        var sms = new WebServiceSMS.SendMessageSoapClient();
        return sms.SendSms(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pwd"], Message, Phone, BranchName, "0");
    }
    catch
    {
        return "Failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it !

Comment: I assumed he could read the XML that was returned by sms.SendSms().